# Why does the connection break when I kill a process on remote host?

Tags: linux, ssh, connection

I login to the remote host (debian) by ssh and execute a command like this

```
ssh user@remote_host "ps -ef | grep process_name | grep -v grep | awk {'print $2'} | xargs kill -9'
```

then the connection breaks.

I ping the remote host and can't receive any response, like the network isn't connected. But when I restart the remote host (power off and power on), everything is ok. I promise that the process killed is only the program written by me and it's father process is "init" process (if the process run in fg and is killed that everything is ok). Is there any one who knows why it happened?

Comment: Wrong site. It is an admin issue, not a programming issue.

Comment: what does `ps -ef | grep process_name | grep -v grep | xargs` return on the remote host? Are you sure it outputs valid arguments for `kill -9`?

Comment: @glglgl it is kind of related to shell programming :)

Answer (score 1):

`ps -ef | grep process_name | grep -v grep` gives not only the **pid** of what you want to kill, but also other information such as the uid, command of the process which may kill something unexpectly. More unfortunately, its **ppid** (parent pid, for you is 1) is also showed, then you know what will happen.

You may try

```
ssh user@remote_host "pkill process_name"
```

or

```
ssh user@remote_host "ps -eo pid,cmd | grep process_name | grep -v grep | cut -d' ' -f2 | xargs kill -9"
```

Or you can first get its output:

```
ssh user@remote_host "ps -ef | grep process_name | grep -v grep"
```

and then filter the pid yourself.

Comment: I'm sorry, I execute "ssh user@remote_host "ps -ef | grep process_name | grep -v grep | awk {'print $2'} | xargs kill -9", I make a mistake in my question.

Comment: So does `ssh user@remote_host "ps -ef | grep process_name | grep -v grep | awk {'print $2'}"` just show your process's pid? If so, I can not help you if you would not give more details.

Comment: I just try again, i only execute ssh user@remote_host "ps -ef | grep process_name | grep -v grep | awk {'print $2'}" on local, and I find the remote host return the information which is the same with "ps -ef | grep process_name | grep -v grep", and then I try to execute  "ps -ef | grep process_name | grep -v grep | awk {'print $2'}" on remote host, it's only show the PID, do you know why the same command return differnt info?

Comment: ER1:~# ssh root@2001:da8:215:3566::1 "ps -ef | grep iperf | grep -v grep | awk {'print $2'}" and the remote host return 
"root     18776     1  0 03:37 ?        00:00:00 iperf -u -V -s -t 10000 -p 9999", why awk don't work ?

Comment: Yeah, I just found it. Just add a "\" before "$". It seems that when you pass a command to `ssh`, it just redirect it to `bash -c` to execute. You can try `ssh user@remote_host "echo $0"`, for me, it shows `/bin/bash`.

Comment: thank you. But I found the problem still exists. Just know, I try to ssh root@2001:da8:215:3566::1, and I input the ps -ef | grep process_name and then I copy the pid, and execute "kill -9 PID", then it happened again, I think it's not the init process killed problem. It confuses me

Comment: Now you may give some info about your program :)

Comment: I found that I could login the remote host by ipv4, but not ipv6. I use pstree and found there are some child processes, I think that the child process maybe do some thing about ipv6. When I use kill -9, then the child processes are all killed, then the ipv6 crash. Now I use kill -2 to kill it, it works well. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder that the command you are showing us even ran without errors. As mentioned in the other answer, you are passing too many things to `xargs`/`kill` which they treat as garbage.

Use something like this *to extract only the PID an kill it*

```
ps -ef | grep process_name | grep -v grep | awk '{print $3}' | xargs kill -9
```

Comment: I make a mistake, I forget to input awk {'print $2'} in my description. I try to ssh the remote host, and ps -ef to get the pid, and kill -9 pid myself, network crash still happen

Comment: What is your program doing? Can you paste your program here if small or in pastebin?

Comment: Yeah, I found it, the program make some child processes, and the child process do something about ipv6-table, when I kill -9 the parent process, the child processes will be killed too, so the ipv6-table make some mistake, then the ipv6 connection break, thank you for your help